# Highlight matched date on yearly Calendar based on different criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Been working on this a while and need some help, keep running into dead ends.

I have a table that populates customer information of jobs, we need to it is as service/commission, this also populates on to the table, the problem then starts that I have mutliple criteria that I would like to highlight with conditional formatting on the calendar picture below.

[image: Table]
I have already managed to conditional format two values, one set value (bank holidays), and Commission. 
**`=IF(MATCH(O10,StartDates,0),TRUE,FALSE)`** 
I can't see to get conditional format for service, without overwiriting, or over populting the calendar with highlights.

Here is picture of the table being used to grab most of the data.

[image: table]

What is a way I can conditional format any date in the Calender dependant on the values in the table? First criteria - Work Scope titled column - (Service/Comission) and second criteria - Start Date.

The next step which is not essential after the above would be to highlight a range of dates based upon the start and finish date in the table.

I already have a date range on another sheet with a different purpose which could be used in a way, I'm not 100% who this works though. 
**`=AND($L$4<>"",$S$4<>"",$L$4<=$S$4,$L$4<=P8,$S$4>=P8)`**

Imagine for the date range highlight below with the connecting formula directly above -
[image: table]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59628680/edit) and post the column headers in the images to understand what is O10 and other formulas.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with [tag:vba], I see no VBA in the question.

Comment: Updated images and added another for last fomula reference